# Draw a cube under extension and torsion at the same time

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3d

I would like to draw a cube under extension and torsion simultaneously as this figure: [image: twisted and extended cube]

I have tried with the extension part (attached code), but don’t know how to combine it with the torsion part.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d, perspective, calc, bending}
%
\definecolor{myRed}{RGB}{180,80,80}
\definecolor{myGreen}{RGB}{55,175,85}
\begin{document}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, 3d view={65}{25}]
        %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \def\h{1 * 5}
        \def\w{1 * 5}
        \def\d{1 * 5}
        \coordinate (a) at ( 0, 0, 0);
        \coordinate (b) at (\d, 0, 0);
        \coordinate (c) at (\d,\w, 0);
        \coordinate (d) at ( 0,\w, 0);
        \coordinate (e) at ( 0, 0,\h);
        \coordinate (f) at (\d, 0,\h);
        \coordinate (g) at (\d,\w,\h);
        \coordinate (h) at ( 0,\w,\h);
        \coordinate (m) at (\d/2,\w/2,\h);
        
        \tikzset{
            face/.style = {fill opacity=0.5},
            edge/.style = {draw, thin, line join=round},
            top/.style = {edge,face,fill=black!30},
            bottom/.style = {edge, face, fill=yellow!90},
            side/.style = {edge, face, fill=myGreen!40},
            label/.style = {fill=white, inner sep=0.5ex},
            rot/.style={ultra thick,-{latex[bend]}},
            fixedbot/.style = {edge, face, fill=black!50},
        };
        
        \draw[bottom,draw opacity=0.5] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- cycle;
        \draw[thick, dashed, orange] (a) node[below left]{$\mathbf{A}$} -- (g) node[above right]{$\mathbf{B}$};
        \draw[top]                     (e) -- (f) -- (g) -- (h) -- cycle;
        
        \draw[side,draw opacity=0.2]   (d) -- (a) -- (e) -- (h) -- cycle;
        \draw[side,draw opacity=0.2]   (c) -- (d) --(h) -- (g) -- cycle;
        \draw[side,fill opacity=0.5]   (a) -- (b) -- (f) -- (e) -- cycle;
        \draw[side,fill opacity=0.5]   (b) -- (c) -- (g) -- (f) -- cycle;
    
        %BCs labels
        \draw[draw=none] (e) -- (g) node[pos=0.8] {$\Omega_\mathsf{top}$}; 
        \draw[draw=none] (a) -- (c) node[pos=0.5] {$\Omega_\mathsf{bottom}$};
    
        %Coordinates
        \draw[thick,-latex] (a) -- (2,0,0) node[above] {$x$};
        \draw[thick,-latex] (a) -- (0,2,0) node[left=0.5ex] {$y$};
        \draw[thick,-latex] (a) -- (0,0,2) node[left]  {$z$};
        
        \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
            \draw[help lines] (-1,-1) grid[step=5] (5.9,5.9); 
            \draw[latex-latex] (a |- 45:-2) -- (b |- 45:-2) node[midway,label] {$b$};
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=0]
            \draw[latex-latex] (b |- 45:9) -- (c |- 45:9) node[midway,label] {$b$};
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[canvas is zx plane at y=-1]
            \draw[latex-latex] (a |- 45:-1) -- (e |- 45:-1) node[midway,above,label] {$b$};
        \end{scope}
    
        %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Deformed cube 
        \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=6.0]
            \coordinate (e1) at ( 0, 0,\h);
            \coordinate (f1) at (\d, 0,\h);
            \coordinate (g1) at (\d,\w,\h);
            \coordinate (h1) at ( 0,\w,\h);
            
            \draw[dash dot, top]                     (e1) -- (f1) -- (g1) -- (h1) -- cycle; 
            \draw[dash dot]   (d) -- (a) -- (e1) -- (f1) -- cycle;
            \draw[dash dot]   (c) -- (d) -- (f1) -- (g1) -- cycle;
            \draw[dash dot]   (a) -- (b) -- (h1) -- (e1) -- cycle;
            \draw[dash dot]   (b) -- (c) -- (g1) -- (h1) -- cycle;

        \end{scope}
        %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \begin{scope}[canvas is zx plane at y=-1]
            \draw[latex-latex] (e |- 45:-1) -- (e1 |- 45:-1)  node[midway,label] {$\lambda_z$};
        \end{scope}
        %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple approach, plotting a 3d function that draws the distorted edges. A couple of `\foreach` commands and you have it.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}

% colors
\definecolor{myRed}  {RGB}{180, 80, 80}
\definecolor{myGreen}{RGB}{ 55,175, 85}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(-0.5908cm,-0.4452cm)},y={(0.8068cm,-0.3260cm)},z={(0cm,0.8340cm)},line cap=round,line join=round]
  \def\l {4}   % length
  \def\ra{40}  % rotation angle
  \def\ex{1}   % extension
  % green cube
  \foreach\i in {0,1}
  {%
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=\i*\l]
      \draw[myGreen] (-0.5*\l,-0.5*\l) rectangle (0.5*\l,0.5*\l);
    \end{scope}
  }
  \foreach\i in {45,135,225,315}
  {%
    \draw[myGreen] (\i:{0.5*sqrt(2)*\l}) --++ (0,0,\l); 
  }
  % distorted red cube
  \begin{scope}[rotate around z=\ra,canvas is xy plane at z=\l+\ex]
    \draw[myRed] (-0.5*\l,-0.5*\l) rectangle (0.5*\l,0.5*\l);
  \end{scope}
  \foreach\i in {45,135,225,315}
  {%
    \draw[myRed] plot[domain=0:1,samples=6,smooth] ({0.5*sqrt(2)*\l*cos(\x*\ra+\i)},{0.5*sqrt(2)*\l*sin(\x*\ra+\i)},{\x*(\l+\ex)});
  }
  % dashed lines (could be removed)
  \foreach\i in {0.2,0.4,...,0.8}
  {
    \begin{scope}[rotate around z={\i*\ra},canvas is xy plane at z={\i*(\l+\ex)}]
      \draw[very thin,myRed,dashed] (-0.5*\l,-0.5*\l) rectangle (0.5*\l,0.5*\l);
    \end{scope}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is what the code produces:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you provided, you can only calculate the new coordinates of e1, f1, g1 and h1, via a rotation along the z axis, then outside the 3D scope, draw the edges using `[out=90,in=90]`.
Here, I didn't calculate correctly, but just made it turn a bit roughly, just to see how it will work, but adding the correct rotation calculus is no big deal, I think.

[image: torsion and extension of a cube]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d, perspective, calc, bending}
%
\definecolor{myRed}{RGB}{180,80,80}
\definecolor{myGreen}{RGB}{55,175,85}
\begin{document}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, 3d view={65}{25}]
        %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \def\h{1 * 5}
        \def\w{1 * 5}
        \def\d{1 * 5}
        \coordinate (a) at ( 0, 0, 0);
        \coordinate (b) at (\d, 0, 0);
        \coordinate (c) at (\d,\w, 0);
        \coordinate (d) at ( 0,\w, 0);
        \coordinate (e) at ( 0, 0,\h);
        \coordinate (f) at (\d, 0,\h);
        \coordinate (g) at (\d,\w,\h);
        \coordinate (h) at ( 0,\w,\h);
        \coordinate (m) at (\d/2,\w/2,\h);
        
        \tikzset{
            face/.style = {fill opacity=0.5},
            edge/.style = {draw, thin, line join=round},
            top/.style = {edge,face,fill=black!30},
            bottom/.style = {edge, face, fill=yellow!90},
            side/.style = {edge, face, fill=myGreen!40},
            label/.style = {fill=white, inner sep=0.5ex},
            rot/.style={ultra thick,-{latex[bend]}},
            fixedbot/.style = {edge, face, fill=black!50},
        };
        
        \draw[bottom,draw opacity=0.5] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- cycle;
        \draw[thick, dashed, orange] (a) node[below left]{$\mathbf{A}$} -- (g) node[above right]{$\mathbf{B}$};
        \draw[top]                     (e) -- (f) -- (g) -- (h) -- cycle;
        
        \draw[side,draw opacity=0.2]   (d) -- (a) -- (e) -- (h) -- cycle;
        \draw[side,draw opacity=0.2]   (c) -- (d) --(h) -- (g) -- cycle;
        \draw[side,fill opacity=0.5]   (a) -- (b) -- (f) -- (e) -- cycle;
        \draw[side,fill opacity=0.5]   (b) -- (c) -- (g) -- (f) -- cycle;
    
        %BCs labels
        \draw[draw=none] (e) -- (g) node[pos=0.8] {$\Omega_\mathsf{top}$}; 
        \draw[draw=none] (a) -- (c) node[pos=0.5] {$\Omega_\mathsf{bottom}$};
    
        %Coordinates
        \draw[thick,-latex] (a) -- (2,0,0) node[above] {$x$};
        \draw[thick,-latex] (a) -- (0,2,0) node[left=0.5ex] {$y$};
        \draw[thick,-latex] (a) -- (0,0,2) node[left]  {$z$};
        
        \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
            \draw[help lines] (-1,-1) grid[step=5] (5.9,5.9); 
            \draw[latex-latex] (a |- 45:-2) -- (b |- 45:-2) node[midway,label] {$b$};
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=0]
            \draw[latex-latex] (b |- 45:9) -- (c |- 45:9) node[midway,label] {$b$};
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[canvas is zx plane at y=-1]
            \draw[latex-latex] (a |- 45:-1) -- (e |- 45:-1) node[midway,above,label] {$b$};
        \end{scope}
    
        %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Deformed cube 
        \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=6.0]
%            \coordinate (e1) at ( 0, 0,\h);
%            \coordinate (f1) at (\d, 0,\h);
%            \coordinate (g1) at (\d,\w,\h);
%            \coordinate (h1) at ( 0,\w,\h);

            \def\torsion{.7}
            \coordinate (e1) at ( 0-\torsion, 0+\torsion,\h);
            \coordinate (f1) at (\d-\torsion, 0-\torsion,\h);
            \coordinate (g1) at (\d+\torsion,\w-\torsion,\h);
            \coordinate (h1) at ( 0+\torsion,\w+\torsion,\h);
            
            \draw[dash dot, top]  (e1) -- (f1) -- (g1) -- (h1) -- cycle; 
            \draw[dash dot]   (d) -- (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle;
            
        \end{scope}
        \draw[dash dot]   (a) to[out=90,in=-90] (e1);
        \draw[dash dot]   (b) to[out=90,in=-90] (h1);
        \draw[dash dot]   (c) to[out=90,in=-90] (g1);
        \draw[dash dot]   (d) to[out=90,in=-90] (f1);
        %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \begin{scope}[canvas is zx plane at y=-1]
            \draw[latex-latex] (e |- 45:-1) -- (e1 |- 45:-1)  node[midway,label] {$\lambda_z$};
        \end{scope}
        %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %
\end{document}
```

### EDIT: NOW WITH A REAL ROTATION

In my previous answer, what I did was to add 0.7 to corner coordinates, which results in some enlargement of the top surface. And that's inacurate.
I think you'd rather have a real rotation of your top square, so here's what I did to achieve that. It's not better, drawingwise, but it's more acurate, so you just have to pick whatever solution you prefer.
[image: V2]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d, perspective, calc, bending}
%
\definecolor{myRed}{RGB}{180,80,80}
\definecolor{myGreen}{RGB}{55,175,85}
\begin{document}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm, 3d view={65}{25}]
        %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \def\h{1 * 5}
        \def\w{1 * 5}
        \def\d{1 * 5}
        \coordinate (a) at ( 0, 0, 0);
        \coordinate (b) at (\d, 0, 0);
        \coordinate (c) at (\d,\w, 0);
        \coordinate (d) at ( 0,\w, 0);
        \coordinate (e) at ( 0, 0,\h);
        \coordinate (f) at (\d, 0,\h);
        \coordinate (g) at (\d,\w,\h);
        \coordinate (h) at ( 0,\w,\h);
        \coordinate (m) at (\d/2,\w/2,\h);
        
        \tikzset{
            face/.style = {fill opacity=0.5},
            edge/.style = {draw, thin, line join=round},
            top/.style = {edge,face,fill=black!30},
            bottom/.style = {edge, face, fill=yellow!90},
            side/.style = {edge, face, fill=myGreen!40},
            label/.style = {fill=white, inner sep=0.5ex},
            rot/.style={ultra thick,-{latex[bend]}},
            fixedbot/.style = {edge, face, fill=black!50},
        };
        
        \draw[bottom,draw opacity=0.5] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- cycle;
        \draw[thick, dashed, orange] (a) node[below left]{$\mathbf{A}$} -- (g) node[above right]{$\mathbf{B}$};
        \draw[top]                     (e) -- (f) -- (g) -- (h) -- cycle;
        
        \draw[side,draw opacity=0.2]   (d) -- (a) -- (e) -- (h) -- cycle;
        \draw[side,draw opacity=0.2]   (c) -- (d) --(h) -- (g) -- cycle;
        \draw[side,fill opacity=0.5]   (a) -- (b) -- (f) -- (e) -- cycle;
        \draw[side,fill opacity=0.5]   (b) -- (c) -- (g) -- (f) -- cycle;
    
        %BCs labels
        \draw[draw=none] (e) -- (g) node[pos=0.8] {$\Omega_\mathsf{top}$}; 
        \draw[draw=none] (a) -- (c) node[pos=0.5] {$\Omega_\mathsf{bottom}$};
    
        %Coordinates
        \draw[thick,-latex] (a) -- (2,0,0) node[above] {$x$};
        \draw[thick,-latex] (a) -- (0,2,0) node[left=0.5ex] {$y$};
        \draw[thick,-latex] (a) -- (0,0,2) node[left]  {$z$};
        
        \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
            \draw[help lines] (-1,-1) grid[step=5] (5.9,5.9); 
            \draw[latex-latex] (a |- 45:-2) -- (b |- 45:-2) node[midway,label] {$b$};
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=0]
            \draw[latex-latex] (b |- 45:9) -- (c |- 45:9) node[midway,label] {$b$};
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[canvas is zx plane at y=-1]
            \draw[latex-latex] (a |- 45:-1) -- (e |- 45:-1) node[midway,above,label] {$b$};
        \end{scope}
    
        %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Deformed cube 
        \begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=6.0]
        
            \begin{scope}[rotate around={-15:(.5*\w ,0.5*\d)},canvas is xy plane at z=\h]
                
                \path (0, 0,\h) coordinate (e1) -- (\d, 0,\h) coordinate (f1) -- (\d,\w,\h) coordinate (g1) -- ( 0,\w,\h) coordinate (h1);
                
            \end{scope}     
            
            \draw[dash dot, top]  (e1) -- (f1) -- (g1) -- (h1) -- cycle; 
            \draw[dash dot]   (d) -- (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle;
            
        \end{scope}
        \draw[dash dot]   (a) to[out=90,in=-90] (e1);
        \draw[dash dot]   (b) to[out=90,in=-90] (h1);
        \draw[dash dot]   (c) to[out=90,in=-90] (g1);
        \draw[dash dot]   (d) to[out=90,in=-90] (f1);

        %-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \begin{scope}[canvas is zx plane at y=-1]
            \draw[latex-latex] (e |- 45:-1) -- (e1 |- 45:-1)  node[midway,label] {$\lambda_z$};
        \end{scope}
        %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```